# Bug ao editar perfil

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, perfil

Ao editar o perfil ele pede a data de aniversário (*Deveria ser data de nascimento se não me engano*) e o placehold do input diz que a data é no formato `dd/mm/yyyy` mas ao confirmar as alterações da um erro dizendo que a data deve ser no formato `yyyy/mm/dd`

Comment: Eu ***acho*** que isso se deve porque o sistema é internacional e o formato solicitado é um padrão ISO.

Comment: Está bug já foi reportado neste link: 
http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/30/formatacao-de-data-no-campo-aniversario

Comment: Pelo menos fica a sugestão de mudança de aniversário p/ nascimento.